# walls for 2d array (python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 8x8 2D numpy array where 0 is open space and 1 is obstacle. How do I represent walls? Is hardcoding the walls into the maze with 1's the only way? If you have any good references, that'd help. I know the general layout of the map but as for the walls I don't know where the exact gap/opening is along it. At first I thought I would just hardcode the wall into the array as a row of 1's then write a function that would edit the array when I detect a gap.

```
nmap = numpy.array([  
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],  
            [0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],  
            [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],  
            [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],  
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],  
            #wall  
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],  
            #wall  
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],  
            #wall  
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
```

Comment: what in your opinion is the difference between a wall and an obstacle? if there is none, why not just make it `1`

Comment: This question is too broad. If your maze always has walls in the same spot, why not just hard code it, especially given how small your maze seems to be. If you need something more versatile, you need to provide more specifics on your implementation and how you define things.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a different number for a wall? like `2`

For example something like this:

```
numpy.array([[2,2,2,2,2],
             [2,0,0,1,2],
             [2,0,0,1,2],
             [2,0,1,0,2],
             [2,0,2,2,2],
             [2,0,0,0,2],
             [2,2,2,2,2]])
```

So `0` represents empty space, `1` represents an obstacle, and `2` represents a wall